# MVC4: External (OAuth) authentication & mapping to other tables/entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building an MVC4 application and need to use external authentication (Facebook, etc). I have that working fine. I see the SimpleMembershipProvider creates 2 separate tables to handle this: "**webpages_Membership**" and "**webpages_OAuthMembership**". I need to map other tables (foreign keys) to User ID. The problem is both tables have a user ID which are unrelated to each other.. I could ignore the foreign keys in the database if necessary (don't like that though), but the bigger question is this: in code, how would I determine whether a user is authorized externally or locally so that I know where to get his other info from? Specifically, I have a user profile table where I will map other attributes to.. having 2 different types of user, how does one go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I have learned more about MVC4 and SimpleMembershipProvider and I see now that the User ID on both tables is actually a foreign key to a parent table called UserProfile. So, User IDs will still be unique.. it's just the mappings are a little different to what I was accustomed to with the standard ASP.NET membership provider. Email address and whatever other properties are required can be easily applied to the UserProfile table.